# How to associate calendar with mouse click on clock in Budgie top panel?

Tags: 17.10, budgie

I'd like to reveal the calendar when I click on the clock in the Budgie panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an applet for that.  Called "Calendar" you can replace the existing Clock applet.  When you click the clock a calendar appears

[image]

To install, just run Budgie Welcome - Install Software - Budgie Applets and install the Calendar applet.

Logout and login and use Budgie Settings to add the applet to your panel.

Comment: Thanks very much! I can't check it now - I gave up on it and went to LXQT - but it is encouraging for future reference.